# Drive SDK: Binary Blobs in Realtime Documents

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm working on a web-based **productivity application**.
So I figure Google Drive SDK, in particular the **Drive Realtime API**, would be a good fit for this application.

I imagine that I should store documents as [shortcut files](https://developers.google.com/drive/integrate-create#create_a_shortcut_to_a_file) with attached [realtime models](https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/reference/gapi.drive.realtime.Model), for the following reasons.

- I would like to use the Realtime API
- The documentation says shortcut files provides same user experiences as builtin apps
- There's no standardized format for the kind of documents my app makes
  (So serializing them and letting people sync them to their desktop makes little sense).

However, I need to embed images (binary blobs).
I can't store these in the realtime model, because it's not designed for large blobs.
Please correct me if there's a way to embed binary blobs in to a realtime model.

**So how do I associate binary blobs with a realtime model attached to a shortcut file?**

The only approach I can think of is to store the blobs, in blobstore or the *hidden appdata folder*.
And this would require me to do a cron job to garbage collect blobs, in case the shortcut file they are used in is deleted.

- **Am I missing any obvious solution?**
- **Would it be appropriate use of the hidden appdata folder?** (or would users delete this data and be surprised that all images inside their files, that they didn't delete, have disappeared)
- **Is there any way to be notified when a shortcut file is deleted?**
- **How often should I garbage collect blobs?** (ie. check if the shortcut file they belong to have been deleted)
- **Can I trust that the owner of a shortcut file is never changed?** (if this can happen, how I'm I supposed to garbage collect binary blobs?)

I would like to store the binary blobs on Drive (in the hidden appdata folder).
This way users wouldn't be billed for drive storage for image storage specific to my app.
I imagine that it would seem quite arbitrary to users if they have purchased Drive storage, and then have to purchase app specific storage for my app.

Comment: I'm sorry, there are few contradictions in your question. That's most likely why because you're in the first design stage. Are you planning to store blobs on Drive or not? And why do you think it's not scaling. If you provide more details, I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: I would definitely like to store in drive. Assuming this is appropriate use of the appdata folder, and users wouldn't delete this folder thinking it just configuration files (would this be appropriate).
And can I trust that the owner of the shortcut file, to which the realtime model is attached doesn't change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to store metadata files on appdata, you don't need shortcuts. Touch a blank file on appdata for each blob that you store externally. Build collaborative functionality using these blank files.

You don't have to worry about the ownership of the appdata files, because they cant be changed by the user or another application.

We don't have a notification system at the moment to push changes at the moment. You can poll the [changes resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/changes/list) to see if there are any deletions made. The garbage collection scheduling is about the size of the metadata and how you honor the user's quota. Users will be aware that they are losing data and that may affect your application where they are deleting your app's data.

Comment: I imagined storing shortcut files with attached realtime models as visible files. Just like the realtime playground does. This way the files can be opened from the Drive UI.
(Most of my documents will be JSON, so storing it in a realtime model is a good fit).
---
I didn't realize that I could use the "Changes: list" with only the drive.file permission. This would make garbage collection a lot easier. Thanks!
---
Should I understand from your answer that using appdata to attach binary blobs to realtime models is appropriate use?
(assuming ofcourse that there's a cron job to garbage collect).

Comment: @Burca, are you saying multiple users will be able to see the images stored in a an appdata folder?  How do our apps connect the appdata blobs with the drive files the users can see and manipulate directly?

Comment: @Riley, each user can only see and modify files in their own appdata folder. Just because each request is authenticated with an access token, we know which user's appdata folder you're modifying.

Comment: @BurcuDogan - Ok, that makes sense. It sounds like you are recommending storing images as blobs in appdata, and I'm not understanding how those images will be shared between users.  When you say "externally," I thought you meant "external to the parent file but still in Drive." Did you actually mean totally externally, on a separate service, so that multiple users could access the blobs? If so, do you have any recommendations for managing access to an external service based on permissions on a drive file?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that you probably don't want to store the binary blobs directly in the Realtime document, particularly if they are large, high quality images.  This will bloat the model, and may cause problems if the size gets too big.

Storing them elsewhere in Drive and linking them into the document might make sense.  However, the challenge is that you would need to make sure that all users on the document had permissions to see them. For this reason, I don't think the app data folder will work.  I don't think you can share anything in that folder, so collaborators would not be able to see the images.

You might just store the files in regular folder.  With the right UI, you could make it clear to the user what was happening so they understand why the files are there.

Comment: Using a regular folder is definitely **not a solution**, then it would be better to use blobstore. However, if a store in the owners appfolder, I would be able to get the downloadUrls using "Files: GET" on the serverside (with the stored credentials for the owner).
But this probably wouldn't work if the owner revokes access to my app, but still has the file shared.

Comment: It also means you have to check each user's permissions to the parent file before the files.get call.  It seems like a very awkward solution.

Comment: If I stored blobs on S3 or in blobs store I would still have to check if the file is shared... There is no way around that, unless give blobs an unpredictable URL and assume that anybody with the URL is authorized. But I can do that with appdata files too. The only awkward thing is when uploading a blob from a non-owning user, which would either have to be signed remotely, which isn't documented, or it would have to be proxies through my server. The big plus with using appdata for blobs is that users buy and manage all storage quota through google...